# HTML and CSS photo not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I have a problem. I created a simple navbar and above it, I am trying to display on which page you are currently on and a photo as a logo.
The problem is that the photo appears as a border and it won't display.

This is the HTML code:

```css
This is the CSS code:

    body{
        top: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    nav {   
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:#00bbbb ;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        left: 0px;
        top:40px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    a {
        display: table;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #03A2A2;
        color: white;
        font-size: 13px;
        width: inherit;
        left:0px;
    
    }
    
    .navbarText{
        color:black;
        font-size: 15px;
        top: 10px;
        position: relative;
        
    }
    
    .fas{
        position: relative;
        height: 36px;
        width: 70px;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        top:10px;
        color: #93f7f7;
    }
    
    
    
    a:hover{
        color:#fff;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .heads{ 
        background-color: #26c4c4;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        
        
    }
    
    
    .logo{
        position: relative;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        top: 5px;
    }
    .inline{
        display: inline;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    
    </head>
    <title>Learnin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" </link>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7a7c16be39.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="heads">
            <h1 class="inline">Home</h1>
            <img class="logo inline" href="/Images/Header/logo.jpg"></img>
        </div>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">   
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            <span class="navbarText">Home</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/Tabs/logbook.html">   
            <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
            <span class="navbarText">LogBook</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/Tabs/fleet.html">   
            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
            <span class="navbarText">Fleet</span>
        </a>
    </nav>

    
    </body>  
    </html>
```

And this is how the website looks:
[Website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3WhU.png)

Comment: Please check the image url.

Comment: Should be like <img class="logo inline" src="/Images/Header/logo.jpg"></img>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `href`, the correct attribute is `src`, [learn more here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp),

```html
<img class="logo inline" src="/Images/Header/logo.jpg"></img>
```

also, make sure that the address is correct, some times it can be trick, you can open your website, right click on the element and go to `Inspect` and check if the address is the same that you are expecting

Comment: Thanks man! I forgot that for image it is src not href. Big thanks!

Comment: @Mereics yeah it can be confusing sometimes, I still have this problem even with years of experiences

Answer (score 0):

do this `<img class="logo inline" alt="put alternative text here" src="/Images/Header/logo.jpg"/>`   and fill in the alt for alternative text

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the img isnt showning is because that the image isn't loading itself

Check the URL, make sure it is an image URL
and is valid